# Filtering crunch generated wordlist before saving it

Tags: command-line

I have a small wordlist of 100 words (unwanted strings) saved in a file called `file01`.

I would like to use `crunch` to generate wordlist of 10 characters, but I want to delete all the lines in `file01` from the new crunch's generated wordlist before saving it, to reduce the size of the newly generated file.

What would syntax for that crunch command be?

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, kindly would you please add more clarifications to the question. Please see the answer below and we can modify depending on your needs

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for Crunch is:

```
crunch min max charset options
```

The min and max are the minimum and maximum lengths (respectively) for your desired wordlist. By default charset is not required, but you can use it to limit the characters of your wordlist to the ones you specify. If you choose to use charset then you must maintain the correct order, which is lowUP123@%# (lowercase letters, then uppercase letters, then numbers and finally symbols). You can skip any of them, but the order must always remain the same.

For example:

```
crunch 2 6 qrs347 | grep -vFf file01
```

The command above will produce a wordlist for every possible combination of the characters qrs347 from 2 to 6 characters in length.

You can modify the command depending on your needs

Comment: if I'm interpreting the OP correctly, I think the solution they're looking for would be `crunch ... | grep -vFf file01`, assuming `crunch` outputs to stdout vs writing a file.

Comment: You are almost always correct @JeffSchaller ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much your command is going good with me i already found a command that to pipe crunch output to sed as: crunch 10 10 abcde123456 | sed '/string1/d ; /string2/d ......'  > Fileout